# Get a monthly summary

Tags: mysql, sql, database, querying

I have a database table that contains a column that represents the initial subscription date.
I want a query to get the number of records that exists between two specific dates grouping by months and years.
May anybody help me please.
This is an example of such table.

```
CREATE TABLE objects(
id int primary key,
subscription_date date,
)
```

I want for example to count the objects that exists each month from 12/12/2011 till 12/12/2013
knowing that the objects counted before must be counted again in the next month since they still do exist, and the new objects subscribed in the new dates are added up.

Comment: It's not clear what your output should look like.  Please add sample values and what output you expect from your query.

Answer (score 1):

For month You can try like this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(val) 
FROM objects
GROUP BY MONTH(subscription_date);
```

And for year You can try like this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(val) 
FROM objects
GROUP BY YEAR(subscription_date);
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: This would require Ali to run this query 24 times and manipulate the results to get the data "from 12/12/2011 till 12/12/2013"

Comment: Thanks for the help, and sorry for my late response. I noticed that this problem can be solved easily with data warehousing and data mining techniques.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to create a list of dates and use correlated subqueries or join/aggregation for the calculation.  Assuming you have at least one subscription per month, here is one method:

```
select ym.yr, ym.mon,
       (select count(*)
        from objects o
        where year(o.date) = ym.yr and month(o.date) = ym.mon
       ) as cnt
from (select distinct year(date) as yr, month(date) as mon
      from objects
      where date between '2011-12-12' and '2013-12-12'
     ) ym;
```